# Tracing security policy permissions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe, content-security-policy

Despite having set the following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.speech.is http://bits.speech.is https://bits.speech.is http://speech.is
```

JavaScript is still blocking me from accessing iframe.contentWindow.document:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'
```

From Firefox console after `speech.contentWindow.document` at `http://bits.speech.is`. Chrome gives the more verbose yet still cryptic:

```
SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://bits.speech.is" from accessing a frame with origin "http://208.113.212.187". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
code: 18
message: "Blocked a frame with origin "http://bits.speech.is" from accessing a frame with origin "http://208.113.212.187". Protocols, domains, and ports must match."
name: "SecurityError"
stack: "Error: Blocked a frame with origin "http://bits.speech.is" from accessing a frame with origin "http://208.113.212.187". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.↵    at <anonymous>:2:21↵    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:580:39)↵    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:539:52)↵    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:458:21)"
```

Is there anyway to trace where this security policy is getting set?  How do figure out what else am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best method I was able to find for fine-tuning CSP was a combination of these two:

- looking at browser console
- configuring CSP to sent CSP reports as they sometimes contain more details can console messages

For the latter you'd need to add `report-uri` to your CSP header and I use http://cspbuilder.info/ unique URLs as report collectors. You might also set the `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only` variant until it starts working.

It would also help if you write what browser you are using. The message doesn't look like CSP violation error from Chrome - they are **way** more verbose and really helpful than this one.

Comment: I've added the PHP headers but it's not coming up yet.  I will investigate more later today : )